# Decide for which positive values on a that makes the series converge

Tags: calculus

For which positive values on *a* does the series converge?:

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}na^{\ln(n)}$$

I have tried to rewrite the expression, but that gives me nothing.

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will guess that your $i$ should be an $n$.  If $a$ is positive, we may write it as $e^x$ for some $x$.  Then
$$
na^{\ln(n)}=n(e^x)^{\ln(n)}=ne^{\ln(n^x)}=n(n^x)=n^{x+1}.
$$
Now you've got yourself a $p$-series.

Comment: Yep, changed that. But why can you change a to $$e^x$$ ?

Comment: Ah, we solve x later on and then take the logarithm of that?

Comment: @JulianAssange $x = \ln(a)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the [root test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RootTest.aspx) and see what you get.

Comment: Too bad, root test fails.  I would have written "try the ratio test" but that fails, too.